# Creating 30 areas with equal amount of road in irregular polygon using MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, algorithm, polygon-creation

The result should be something like this just more polygons.

[image]

Does anyone know about a tool, which given a table, can create a number of polygons which will divide the tables object into, for example, 30 amounts of equal length if the object are lines?

I am using MapInfo and can program in Python.

Comment: More criteria are needed to specify a solution.  For instance, one simple method is to sweep a line (which is oriented not to be parallel to any road segment) from left to right across the map; each time the amount of road distance covered increases by 1/30 of the total, slice the map there. Result: 30 parallel non-overlapping slices (which can be completed as rectangles), each containing exactly the same road length.  But would such a solution be acceptable--and if not, why not?

Comment: If you do that you may risk getting 2 pieces of road in the same "slice" which actually not are connected on less you take a detour. Since the area's represent an actual working person, who get's paid, that is not an optimal solution. In my case where the above picture is the very center of Odense where the distance from east to west is approx. 3 km it might be allright. I woould like though that the roads in every slice to be connected.

Comment: Please include that important information in your question. Did you notice that even your illustrated solution does not produce entirely connected pieces?  (There is an orphan road segment at the bottom of the rightmost piece.)

Comment: Yes I will do that in the future. Yes in the bottom and on top right. This is actual data and  there might be a square insted of a road to connect the lines which are roads.